# Accessing Nexus from Eclipse/M2E through httpd with LDAP requirement

Tags: nexus, m2eclipse, httpd.conf

Recently, I configured a Nexus repo on a corporate server at https://mycorporateserver.corporation.com/nexus/.

The way "its always been done" is to put our "apps" on the server and use apache httpd to serve the pages and manage access using ldap.

Nexus is configured for anonymous access, https, localhost only (all works fine).  Then, we used Apache httpd to serve that Nexus page/URI to others using proxypass and reverseproxypass (per instructions in sonatype's documentation).

The catch is that the httpd configuration requires ldap.  So, if I hit the given Nexus URI from a web browser, the browser asks for my corporate login.  I log in with my user name and password and can view the repository as an anonymous user just fine.

I did not configure Nexus for ldap, Nexus provided me read-only anonymous access combined with the ability to log in as an admin from the login menu.

Great.  The problem (not surprising) is when Eclipse/M2E tries to contact the Nexus repository I get:

"could not transfer artifact 'myartifact' from/to nexus (https://mycorporateserver.corporation.com/nexus/): handshake alert."

In my settings.xml, I included

```
<servers>
    <server>
       <id>tried many different versions of the server name including full URI</id>
       <username>username</username>
       <password>password</password>
    <server/>
<servers/>
```

but that doesn't seem to work - which I think makes sense since I'm not trying to login to Nexus but rather supply my credentials to ldap.(?)

In M2E/Eclipse, is there a way to provide the needed LDAP information?

Is it better to not let httpd manage access but configure Nexus to handle everything LDAP?  Is there a better/different way to configure Nexus/httpd/LDAP/Eclipse to solve the problem?

Thanks for all pointers and guidance!

Answer (score 1):

> "could not transfer artifact 'myartifact' from/to nexus
>   (https://mycorporateserver.corporation.com/nexus/): handshake alert."

That's an SSL handshake problem, the Java running Eclipse does not consider the certificate installed on Nexus to be valid.  This is almost certainly because either:

1. The certificate is self signed.
2. The certificate has been signed by a
   private certificate signing authority which is not in the truststore
   of the Java running Eclipse.

Either way the workaround is to install the certificate on Nexus into the trust store of the java running Nexus.

See here for more information:

https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/213464948-How-to-trust-the-SSL-certificate-issued-by-the-HTTP-proxy-server-in-Nexus

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, as I understand it, it was a mismatch between how the VirtualHost and ServerName were defined in the apache httpd configuration.

https://mycorporateserver.corporation.com/nexus/ was the ServerName but the VirtualHost was defined with the ip and port https://mycorporateserver.corporation.com:port.

Original

```
<VirtualHost ip:port>
    ServerName mycorporateserver.corporation.com/nexus/
    ...ldap and proxy pass configs
</VirtualHost>
```

Since we have more than one virtual host containing this ip and port combination, the server looked further into the configuration to find the proper page by reading the ServerName.  Since no ServerNames matched what the clients sent, the handshake error occurred.
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html

Changing ServerName in the httpd conf to include the port solved the handshake error.

Final

```
<VirtualHost ip:port>
    ServerName mycorporateserver.corporation.com:port/nexus/
    ...ldap and proxy pass configs
</VirtualHost>
```

(I'm by no means an apache httpd expert, still want to find out if there is a way to do all this without showing the port in the URL)

Then, when sending a request from Eclipse/M2E to the server, the response was "Unauthorized"

Adding the nexus server plus username and password to settings.xml solved the authorization problem and all worked great!

```
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>password</password>
    <server>
</servers>
```

To ensure passwords were not stored in plain text, instructions at this Maven site were used to create encrypted passwords: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html

In hindsight, the question probably could have been asked better/differently but I didn't yet know what I learned today.